# Hiberate query throws java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.Enum

Tags: hibernate

This query on a repository method

```
@Query(
    "SELECT a FROM AttachmentEntity a " +
        "WHERE (:projectId IS NULL OR a.projectId = :projectId) " +
        "AND (:attachmentTypes IS NULL OR a.attachmentType IN :attachmentTypes) " +
        "AND (:eventType IS NULL OR a.eventType = :eventType) ")
fun getAttachments(
    projectId: Int?,
    attachmentTypes: List<AttachmentType>?,
    eventType: EventType?
): List<AttachmentEntity>
```

throws this exception, when called:

```
class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.Enum (java.util.ArrayList and java.lang.Enum are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

When I remove `:attachmentTypes IS NULL OR`, it works.

Could this be a bug in the hibernate query parser?
I could get around this by building the query inside the method, but is there another way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was already reported please see [HHH-15968](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15968).

Answer (score 1):

There is dirty fix for it, using spEL:

```
AND ((:#{#attachmentTypes} IS NULL) OR t.attachmentTypes IN :attachmentTypes)
```

Unfortunatelly bug ticket mentioned above get closed as Hibernate representatives thinks it's not "something which was even considered supported". Which is utterly dummy.